# Install AVConference in my server

Tags: cpanel, red5

I am trying to integrate avconference in my site
i am following the step but as requirements it say need to install red5
http://avconference.net/requirements

i have cpanel access only

anyone can help me pls

Answer (score 0):

You need root access to install avconference. You need at least SSH access after you upload it you will need to run a few commands via putty if you are using windows or your SSH terminal if using linux to install it or you can purchase a hosting that has red5 or FMS pre-installed